# What are thos expressions ${*:1:$#:1} and ${*:1:$# - 1}

Tags: bash, input, parameters, scripting

can somebody explain to me what do this expressions mean ? Too tough for me interpreting this:

```
$(*:1:$#:1)
$(*:1:$# - 1)
```

They are used in the beginning of the script:

```
!#/bin/bash
file=${*:1:$#:1}
egrep_command = `./generate_command $file ${*:1:$#-1}
```

I know that the last parameter is a name of a file and I'm interested to activate generate_command on all the other parameters from the first to the one before the last. Some how that should do what I've told, I jsut don't understand the whole syntax.

Comment: Are you sure, it wasn't `${*:1:$#-1}` ?

Comment: Too many typos in the script. Even shebang is wrong. It should be `#!`, not `!#`. Spaces around `=` in assignment. Use http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: ok, but the point is clear, isn't it? I mean what should it do. The accurate correctness isn't the point.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear at all because there's a big difference between `${}` and `$()`. We can't explain syntax if we don't know for sure what the real syntax is.

Comment: I think it should be {}, but the font is really really small and that's all I got.

Comment: You can increase the font size in your terminal or editor, you know.

Comment: It's in a book ) and it's hard to differ in the book itself. Seems like {}

Comment: Also, it's *wrong*. `$*` is entirely inappropriate for use -- will mangle arguments with spaces &c; if the book's author knew what they were doing, they'd have used `$@` instead (and they would have quoted correctly). Explaining what something **that isn't even correct** does is... not exactly a great use of our time.

Comment: Also, any kind of `generate_command` call storing results to a scalar variable is inherently broken; see BashFAQ #50 for a description of how and why it fails: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: What is the book telling you how to do? We could certainly provide a better version.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax in question is [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

The script given, is attempting -- badly and incorrectly -- to assign the last variable on its command line to `file`, and pass the others through.

Below is a version with the most obvious tactical (as opposed to strategic) bugs corrected (albeit with some assumptions about intent, as it's impossible to tell what buggy code was *intended* to mean without a human-language description):

```
#!/bin/bash

# assign last variable in "$@" to file
# This is taking the very last item in the list, by starting at the position named by the
# total number of arguments
file=${@:$#}

# call generate_command with that file first, and all other arguments after
egrep_command=$(./generate_command "$file" "${@:1:$#-1}")
```

Even with those bugs corrected, this is **extremely** unwise code: If it's storing a command in a scalar (string) variable, it's prone to all the bugs described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). (If it intends to work around some of them with `eval`, then it introduces security vulnerabilities as well).

Also, using `$*` without quotes rather than `$@` inside quotes in the original code concatenated all the selected arguments together with spaces -- or, if the `IFS` variable was set, its first character -- between them, and then split the items back out into pieces whenever any character in `IFS` (or, by default, tabs, spaces, and newlines) existed, evaluating each piece as a glob pattern. If you don't want all this logic done, don't use `$*` -- use `$@`, and use it inside quotes (except in a context, such as variable assignment, where quotes are unnecessary).

---

Focusing on the PE that is the core of the question:

`"${@:start:len}"` expands to `len` items, beginning at position `start`, from the special array `"$@"`. If you had your own array, say, named `arr`, you might write something similar as `${arr[@]:start:len}`.

Comment: I'm afraid, `${@:len:start}` is wrong, it is `${@:start:len}`... Accordingly, `file=${@:1:$#-1}` will assign all but last elements to the variable file; not the last element. Other than this mistake & corresponding mistake in description, the answer is correct. Plus, it suggests correctly about many good practices.